# using Angular's jqlite to select elements of the same type

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm doing some HTML5 Video to Canvas manipulations. I've made a directive where I need to select a few children elements.  I've had no problem doing this until now because I have 2 `canvas` tags.

html:

```
<div id="video-to-canvas" canvas-video-map>

  <video id="menu-video" loop  controls  preload="auto">
    <source src="../../images/clouds.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

  <canvas id='menu-canvas'></canvas>
  <canvas id='back-canvas'></canvas>

</div>
```

js:

```
            //grabs the childrend of the directive for selection e.g. video && canvas tag
            var el = {
                video:    element.find('video')[0],
               // how do i select between these two canvas tags properly
                canvas:   element.find('canvas')[0],
                back:     element.find('canvas')[0]

            };
```

Also If i try to `el.canvas.append('<canvas></canvas>)` i get a type error
Extra code

```
         .directive('canvasVideoMap', function($window) {
            return {
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    angular.element(document).ready(function() {

                //grabs the childrend of the directive for selection e.g. video && canvas tag
                var el = {
                    video:    element.find('video')[0],
                    canvas:   element.find('canvas')[0],
                    back:     element.find('canvas')[0]

                };
                //tests to see if the video is ready
                el.video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(){
                    scope.$emit('load::video');

                }, false);

                //inits the context and sizes
                var context = el.canvas.getContext('2d');
                var cw = Math.floor(el.canvas.clientWidth );
                var ch = Math.floor(el.canvas.clientHeight);
                el.canvas.width = cw;
                el.canvas.height = ch;


                //waits for broadcast from mainctrl
                scope.$on('load::menu', function() {
                    el.video.play();  
                });

                //adds the event listener if the video is playing
                el.video.addEventListener('play', function(){
                    draw(this,context,cw,ch);
                },false);



            }, false);
        //the recursive draw loop
           function draw(v,c,w,h) {
                if(v.paused || v.ended) return false;
                c.drawImage(v,0,0,w,h);

                //creates gradient
                var grd = c.createLinearGradient(0,0, w,h);

                //configures gradient fill
                grd.addColorStop(0,"hsla(268,92%,19%,.9)");
                grd.addColorStop(1,"hsla(30,100%,50%,.9)");

                //sets gradient
                c.fillStyle = grd;
                c.fillRect(0,0,w,h);

                //sets blending mode of gradient
                c.globalCompositeOperation = "color";

                //recursive loop
                setTimeout(draw,20,v,c,w,h);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's native ID selector

```
var el = {
    video:    element.find('video')[0],
    canvas:   document.getElementById('menu-canvas'),
    back:     document.getElementById('back-canvas')
};
```

Or for some reason if you want to stick with Angular methods and the two canvases are always loaded in the same order, you can just specify the index number on the array returned from `.find`

```
var el = {
    video:    element.find('video')[0],
    canvas:   element.find('canvas')[0],
    back:     element.find('canvas')[1]
};
```

Lastly, you can load jQuery and utilize the full CSS selector that jQuery provides

```
var el = {
    video:    element.find('video')[0],
    canvas:   element.find('#menu-canvas'),
    back:     element.find('#back-canvas')
};
```

As to the second part of your question, can you provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that recreates the error?